# Equivalent of OpenCV statement in Java using JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I want to know how to construct the following C++ statement in OpenCV using JavaCV:

```
float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
```

To get the Radius of a circle detected using cvHoughCircles(). Obviously Java doesn't use pointer so I have no idea how to do this in Java. The code I have so far so you can see it context:

```
lines = cvHoughCircles(frame2, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, 300, 60, 10, 600);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.total(); i++) {
    //Would like the code to go here
    CvPoint2D32f point = new CvPoint2D32f(cvGetSeqElem(lines, i));
    cvCircle(src, cvPoint((int)point.x(), (int)point.y()), 3, CvScalar.WHITE, -1, 8, 0);
    Point p = new Point((int)point.x(), (int)point.y());
    points.add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaCPP maps C/C++ arrays/pointers to Pointer objects, so we *can* access it in the same way as in C/C++, i.e.:

```
FloatPointer p = new FloatPointer(cvGetSeqElem(circles, i));
int radius = Math.round(p.get(2));
```